# node.js heroku - app/web.1: Error: no template specified

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am getting this error in my heroku node.js app. It was running fine and all of a sudden started seeing this error whenever we try to access the app and we get "Internal Server Error". The same node.js app runs fine in my local. Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Spoke with heroku support but they couldn't help much.

```
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:  Error: no template specified 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at engine (/app/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:90:29) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at View.proto.render (/app/node_modules/engine-munger/lib/expressView.js:45:9) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at EventEmitter.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at serverError (/app/node_modules/kraken-js/middleware/500.js:31:17) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at serverError (eval at createToggleWrapper (/app/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/meddleware/index.js:133:51), <anonymous>:1:77) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at Layer.handle_error (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at IncomingMessage.next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at done (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:956:25) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at engine (/app/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:90:20) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at View.proto.render (/app/node_modules/engine-munger/lib/expressView.js:45:9) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:      at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10) 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=careerconnections.herokuapp.com request_id=ed9bab4f-42c4-4734-8a22-22e174e90f3f fwd="221.135.191.2,173.224.163.83" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=93ms status=500 bytes=238 
Aug 27 21:42:22 careerconnections app/web.1:  ::ffff:10.171.126.71 - - [28/Aug/2015:04:42:21 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 22 "https://careerconnections.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Check the express version in your local and remote machine

Comment: Did you fix this? If so, can you please submit your answer and accept it?

Comment: We couldn't resolve this issue. Talked to heroku support team and was told that it should be an application issue. But our application runs fine in local dev environment. We then deployed our application in aws as a workaround to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't resolve this issue. Talked to heroku support team and was told that it should be an application issue. But our application runs fine in local dev environment. We then deployed our application in aws as a workaround to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you're invoking adaro's `engine()` function without providing a `file` argument:

- https://github.com/krakenjs/adaro/blob/467ec9aa8cc00a9326ed50cd3ca7fc3ac2b20ee3/lib/engine.js#L134

If it's working locally, check that updated versions haven't broken inter-compatibility between express, dust, adaro, etc:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --quiet --production
npm start
```

It's best to set fixed versions in package.json (`npm install --save --save-exact foobar`).

Comment: @huntelloftis. Thanks for your kind reply. I tried the steps you mentioned to reproduce the issue locally and I couldn't reproduce it locally. It runs fine. Also I did a search for "engine()" in all the files and I can see them only in express\History.md file and the actual like is "app.engine()". I also checked the package.json file and found that all dependencies are version-ed properly.  
the github path for the source code is https://github.com/vinaiarun/ScholarMatch. If you have some time could please take a look at it. Because of this issue the website is down for the past 10 days.